# How to do left align data in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to generate a text file with data by executing a procedure.
But while generating text file, next or previous column value should not enter into other column value. Please see the below EX for more details.

### Example

We have 2 columns of type `Varchar(5)` in a table. I want to generate a file with this data.
So 5 characters will be allowed for each column.

**Case 1:** If first column is having 5 characters data(ex:'qwert'), we will get the data and second column value will come beside this. No problem. it works fine.

**Case 2:** If first column is having 3 characters data(ex:'asd'), we will get this but second column value should not enter into 4th position of 1st column value in the text file. if the data of the 1st column is < 5 character, it should print and it should print remaining as blanks.

Note: No delimiter required in text file.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you need, that is having first column printed everytime with 5 chars, you could simply use this

```
SELECT LEFT(col1 + "     ", 5) AS col1, col2
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the same 2 days back. But in our client machine xp_cmdshell is not enabled. It was throwing the same error when i was running the procedure through xp_cmdshell.

Is there some other solution without enabling xp_cmdshell?
If there is no solution, i will ask our client to enable xp_cmdshell.

Comment: @chandrasekhar: that's the only solution I know, but I'm not a SQL Server manager...